# How we can use single BottomBar in whole Application like ActionBar in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, bottombar

I use https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar module for implement bottombar feature in application

The problem is that i include a BottomBar layout in each activity

Is there any way how can i use BottomBar in only once therefore I am able to use that single BottomBar in whole Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one best solution for use single BottomBar in whole Applicaiton
I create single Activity that is **MainActivity** and rest of all **Fragments**

Generally when we replace fragment with another fragment, we can't get previous fragment for that solution i write below code

```
FragmentManager fm;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

public ProductListAdapter(Context context, List<ProductItem> items, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.fm = fm;
        fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

btnProductMainViewMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                            android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new ProductDetailFragment());
                    **fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);** // with this line you can back to previous fragment
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a this [library](https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav). It works with the BottomBar library that you're using. Basically, you will have to work with fragments instead of activities. So you just have to include your BottomBar layout in the main activity.

Comment: I use bottomBar in **activity_main.xml** and I use 4 different Fragments in MainActivity. In thai i have one **ProductFragment**
In that when i click on _View More_ Button it redirects me on **ProductDetailsActivity.java**. So how can i use single BottomBar @Ander Going

Comment: create only single activity in your app rest all should be fraement for that

Comment: I can't get ProductFragment while i replace that with ProductDetailFragment when i clicked on Back Arrow button from ActionBar.

Do u have any solution for that problem@Bharatsingh

Answer (score 1):

You should use [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) which is added in version 25.0.0

Comment: How can i use single BottomNavigationView in whole application??

Comment: Its better to use fragments in  viewpager, which will allow you to keep botttomnavview constatnr throughout, you can refer [link](http://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/) for more details